# How to debug a minified JS frontend error with no stacktrace?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, runtime-error, vendor

I am getting this error in Rollbar:

```
File https://some.externally-hosted.vendor/library.js  line 4 col 1832 in Anonymous function
```

That's literally it.

What can you do here? Without source maps (third-party lib), what can you do with this line/col information to find the culprit? Can anything else be done to debug?

Another error is just this line, no stacktrace:

```
File https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js  line (unknown)0 in [anonymous]
```

Even less information...

Or best of all, this one-liner:

```
File (unknown) line (unknown)0 in [anonymous]
```

Comment: a) don't use a third-party lib but host it yourself so that you get a stacktrace b) ask the library vendor to debug it

Comment: Try and reproduce the error in your development environment

Comment: It seems to be a network issue that sporadically occurs ever n minutes. Hard to test locally.